# PMML (for text categorization) in use

Tags: nlp, pmml

I have generated PMML file for text categorization using jpmml-sklearn (in python) using the following code:

```
Textpipeline = PMMLPipeline([
    ("tf-idf", TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = "word", preprocessor = None, strip_accents = None, token_pattern = None, tokenizer = Splitter(), stop_words = "english", ngram_range = (1, 2), norm = None,max_features = 50)),
    ("classifier", SGDClassifier())
])

Textpipeline.fit(data.data, data.target)

from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml

sklearn2pmml(Textpipeline, "TextMiningClassifier_SGD_Classifier.pmml", with_repr = True)
```

Now, I want to put this PMML (trained model) in action where I can import it (in some platform, say JAVA or some other platform) and categorize input text.

Would be great to know the steps on how I can import the above PMML model, and generate predictions on a new dataset (in this case just the categorization of input text).

Would appreciate any help in this.